# Radon HD 6870 compatibility with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, video, graphics-card, ubuntu-11.10

Does anyone have experience with the XFX Radeon HD 6870 on Ubuntu 11.10? I've googled and the best I could find was someone getting the card to 'work' on linux. Nothing specific about ubuntu and this card.

Specifically, I want to be able to use the full 1900x1200 resolution and watch 1080p movies.

If yes, was it very complicated to get working?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you try asking your question on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Dennis' advice and asked the question on AskUbuntu. The question is here and has been answered. https://askubuntu.com/questions/79015/radon-hd-6870-compatibility-with-ubuntu-11-10

In short, the card does work.

Answer (score 0):

You could ['try' Ubuntu on the computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD). Maybe if you try it before you install it, you'll be able to check the functionality.

Comment: My concern is with buying the card. The store I can get it from has a great deal right now, but they charge a 15% restocking fee if I return it.